# How to combine a list of data frame into a single dataframe using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frame

```r
A1 = data.frame(name = c("a1", "a3", "a5"), cor = c(1, 0.99, 0.93))
A2 = data.frame(name = c("a2", "a3", "a4"), cor = c(1, 0.94, 0.94))
A3 = data.frame(name = c("a3", "a1", "a2", "a6"), cor = c(1, 0.99, 0.94, 0.91))
myList = list(A1, A2, A3)
```

Each data frame is a calculated correlation coefficient (CC).

For instance:

in `A1`, the CC between `a1 and a1` is 1, between `a1 and a3` is 0.99, and between `a1 and a5` is 0.93;

in `A2`, the CC between `a2 and a2` is 1, between `a2 and a3` is 0.94, and between `a2 and a4` is 0.94.

What I want to do is to combine these individual dataframe into a complete one like following:

```r
corMatrix
     a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6
a1 1.00 0.00 0.99 0.00 0.93 0.00
a2 0.00 1.00 0.94 0.94 0.00 0.00
a3 0.99 0.94 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.91
a4 0.00 0.94 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00
a5 0.93 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
a6 0.00 0.00 0.91 0.00 0.00 1.00
```

This `corMatrix` dataframe contains all the correlation information of the above data frames. If the correlation information of two variables are unknown, then `0` is used to represent their CC values, such as variable `a1 and a2`.

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Base R you could do:

```
a <- do.call(rbind,Map(cbind, name1 = c('a1','a2', 'a3'), myList))
b <- unique(rbind(a, setNames(a[c(2,1,3)], names(a))))
xtabs(cor~., b)

    name
name1   a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6
   a1 1.00 0.00 0.99 0.00 0.93 0.00
   a2 0.00 1.00 0.94 0.94 0.00 0.00
   a3 0.99 0.94 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.91
   a4 0.00 0.94 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
   a5 0.93 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
   a6 0.00 0.00 0.91 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does what you're looking for, although it may not be the best way of doing this:

```r
A1 = data.frame(name = c("a1", "a3", "a5"), cor = c(1, 0.99, 0.93))
A2 = data.frame(name = c("a2", "a3", "a4"), cor = c(1, 0.94, 0.94))
A3 = data.frame(name = c("a3", "a1", "a2", "a6"), cor = c(1, 0.99, 0.94, 0.91))
myList = list(A1, A2, A3)

names(myList) = c("a1", "a2", "a3")
myMatrix = dplyr::bind_rows(myList, .id = "name2") |> 
  dplyr::mutate(name2 = factor(name2, levels = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6")),
                name = factor(name, levels = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"))) |> 
  tidyr::complete(name2, name, fill = list(cor = 0)) |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = name2, values_from = cor) |> 
  tibble::column_to_rownames("name") |> 
  as.matrix() 
diag(myMatrix) <- 1
myMatrix[upper.tri(myMatrix)] <- t(myMatrix)[upper.tri(myMatrix)]
```

which returns:

```r
     a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6
a1 1.00 0.00 0.99 0.00 0.93 0.00
a2 0.00 1.00 0.94 0.94 0.00 0.00
a3 0.99 0.94 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.91
a4 0.00 0.94 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00
a5 0.93 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
a6 0.00 0.00 0.91 0.00 0.00 1.00
```

The general idea is that you:

- name the list to make sure you know which correlations they are (could do this programmatically with `paste()` if longer list)
- combine all the list elements together into a dataframe
- fill out all possible elements using factors (again could be done programmatically if required)
- complete to add 0 for missing values
- switch to a matrix, add 1 for diagonal, and make symmetric across the diagonal